# I am not able to print the output on the screen. I am using cppreference side (GCC 12.1 (c++20 )) compiler

Tags: c++, stdthread, counting-semaphore

I am not able to print the output on the screen.I am using cppreference side (GCC 12.1 (c++20
)) compiler,  Is there any deadlock situation in below example. Is there any online compiler i can use for trying this type of examples

```
#include <iostream>
#include <semaphore>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> myVec{};
std::counting_semaphore<1> prepareSignal(2);              // (1)

void prepareWork() 
{

    myVec.insert(myVec.end(), {0, 1, 0, 3});
    std::cout << "Sender: Data prepared."  << '\n';
    prepareSignal.release();                              // (2)
}

void completeWork() 
{

    std::cout << "Waiter: Waiting for data." << '\n';
    prepareSignal.acquire();                              // (3)
    myVec[2] = 2;
    std::cout << "Waiter: Complete the work." << '\n';
    for (auto i: myVec) std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::thread t1(prepareWork);
    std::thread t3(completeWork);
    std::thread t2(completeWork);
    t1.join();
    t3.join();
    t2.join();
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: No deadlock, but undefined behavior. None of the threads are properly sequenced. Semaphores do not sequence.

Comment: If you have read the cppreference page, can you explain in your words how you expect the `counting_semaphore` to work here? Because the initialization is already incorrect, see preconditions here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore/counting_semaphore

Comment: Uh, why the template argument of `counting_semaphore` is smaller than the constructor argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no deadlock, but you have a race condition:

In `completeWork`, `prepareSignal.acquire` does not block the execution (Based on [c++ documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore): *"When the counter is zero, acquire() blocks until the counter is incremented"*). In this case, the counter is set to 2, and there is no other acquire.

So the program may run `completeWork` earlier than `prepareWork`, which will execute `myVec[2] = 2;`. This causes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) since your vector is empty.

You can test such errors using [Address Sanitizer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhpzDFvXopk).

See a live example here that highlights this issue by adding a 1 second sleep delay to `prepareWork`:

https://godbolt.org/z/YYsfq84bd

The address sanitizer output tells you exactly where the error is!

Comment: Also, thread sanitizer will give you more clear information on the data race and without needing to figure out where to test a delay: https://godbolt.org/z/zTqjnr6zE